# Flash CS4 5005 unknown error optimizing byte code

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, compilation

I'm trying to compile my flash project from Flash CS4. But it raises me this error "**5005 unknown error optimizing byte code**" 
Does anybody know the exact solution for this problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: When did you start getting this error - do you have a version of code that didn't cause in this? in that case, what did you add code-wise/FLA-wise to the project? did you try rebuilding from scratch?

Comment: This problem appears whenever i add any code to old version code. I've searched the web, guys say it's the problem when project have grown up very much, a lot of classes, components etc. But didn't find solving solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. 
Thanks to author in this blog: 
http://stefig.blogspot.com/2009/04/5005-unknown-error-optimizing-byte-code.html
Thank you also Amarghosh ;)

Comment: interesting, food for thought if I ever encounter it :)

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error in *CS5*, I tried the following recommended steps that have helped others:

- Unchecked "Compress Movie" in Publish Settings > Flash Tab
- From the top menu, select Control > Delete ASO Files
- Open C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5\Common\First Run\ActionScript 3.0\jvm.ini and changed -Xmx128m to -Xmx1024m
- Add "JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS -Xmx1024m" to system environment variables

None of these worked for me, though. I finally just saved my FLA file under a different name... and voila, it compiled without the error.

Answer (score 0):

Hm....
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Xmx256M could not solve my problem.

Buy when I publish the one which fla file could be published then publish the error one. It will be solved.

Sound ridiculous? You can try it at last.

Comment: You might be facing with different problem.